# Retrieving documents inside of objects in MongoDB and displaying on Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Let's say I want to create a list of a user's scores for all the games the user has played on his account. Each user has an object inside the MongoDB that is attached to his/her _id via a `userId` key and has a `data` key (which contains an array of objects that each has the name of the game and the score of the game). It looks like this:

```
var mongoDB = {userId: "thisistheuserid", 
               data: [{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4}...] };
```

The data's objects look like this:

```
data: {Title: "Name of game",
       Score: 10};
```

What I'm trying to do is display all the game titles and scores to the user in client. I do this via this HTML:

```
{{#each helper}}
            <li>{{Title}}: {{Score}}</li>
          {{/each}}
```

Now, if the documents were just simply inside MongoDB, it's easy to list all the items in client:

```
helper: function(){
  return Collection.find({});
}
```

What I want to do is list all the game titles and scores to the user, but not sure how to do it by going inside 2 objects and one array to get to the information. I can try `find().fetch()`, but that doesn't seem to allow me to actually be able to list all the items.

Right now, for the helper function, I have:

```
helper: function(){
  return Collection.find({userId: this.userId}, {"data.Title": {}});
```

}

The above, if it were to work correctly, would give just the title of the game. But I'm doing something wrong here. I have a feeling this is too easy and am missing one thing which won't allow me to properly display the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a nested object you can simply use `{{#with}} to scope the data context:

```
{{#each helper}}
  {{#with data}}
    <li>{{Title}}: {{Score}}</li>
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

And have your helper simply return `Collection.find()`

In your case your key refers to an array of objects so you have to use an iterator, just nest the `{{#each}}` while referring to the embedded array key:

```
{{#each helper}}
  {{#each data}}
    <li>{{Title}}: {{Score}}</li>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Tried it. It's simply displaying blanks at the moment.

Comment: Oh wait, your data is an array, in that case just nest `{{#each data}}` instead of `{{#with}}`

Comment: Bless you, good sir. Never knew nesting in Blaze was possible. Thanks for the help!